# Facebook SDK 3.22 (android) - me/friends return wrong user's friends id

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want my app to get ids and names of user's friends that have used the app too and find the id I need by the name. Then I want to use feed dialog with parameter "TO" to post to friend's wall. I thought it would be easy. Just use `me/friends`. Here is request:

```
if(session.getState().isOpened()){
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating request");
        Request friendRequest =  new Request(session, "/me/friends", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Complete!" + response.toString());

                JSONArray usersArrays = new JSONArray();

                try {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Converting to userObject");
                    usersArrays = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < usersArrays.length(); i++){
                        Log.i(TAG, "Reading " + i + " user");
                        JSONObject user = usersArrays.getJSONObject(i);

                        Log.i(TAG, "Getting name and id");
                        String userId = user.getString("id");
                        String userName = user.getString("name");

                        Log.i(TAG, "Now checking: " + userName + " with id: " + userId);

                        if (userName.equals(name)){
                            Log.w(TAG, "He was found! Here is his id: " + userId);
                            postToWall(userId);

                        } else if (i == (usersArrays.length() - 1)){
                            Log.e(TAG, name + " does not use the app yet!");
                            //no ways
                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        }
        );

        Log.i(TAG, "Sending request");
        friendRequest.executeAndWait();
```

Here is my response:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"summary":{"total_count":46},"data":[{"id":"383791018465143","name":"Friend Name"}],"paging":{"next":"..."}}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

Then I found [this](http://findmyfacebookid.com/) site and decided to find out friend's id. It was not the same.

When using feed dialog my app crashes with facebook error: `incorrect user`. What can I do about it?

Thanks in advance, Sergey

Comment: If you created your app after 4/30/2014, then you will only have access to an app-scoped user id, which means the set of user ids you have access in your app is only scoped to within your app, and is not the user's public ID.

Comment: How then can I get friends' public ID for the feed dialog? @MingLi

Comment: You can't. You can use the share or message dialog as supplied by the SDK, and from there the user can choose who to post to.

Comment: So, as I understand, I can't post to user's friend wall. Share dialog allows to post only to user's wall and messages are private. Am I right? @MingLi

Comment: That is totally correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MingLi sais I cannot get Facebook ids of user's friends